# Ajax Not working in IOS 9.0 Cordova

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myweb/php",
    success: function (data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function(xhr,textStatus,err)
    {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
        alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
        alert("status: " + xhr.status);
        alert("text status: " + textStatus);
        alert("error: " + err);
    }
});
```

And the result I get is:

```
readyState:0
responseText:""
status:0
text status:error
error:""
```

I try add header in my php, but still not working. The ajax code work before i update my xcode to 7.0 and ios simulator to 9.0.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as i understood the whole ATS (**App Transport Security - iOS 9**) thing, the recommended method from area28 should not be the one you're using inside an application.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> 
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

**This will allow all external requests to every domain what is definitively not the way you should use it**. In my opinion you should define a new `<dict>` inside your `info.plist` and add this code to it (to edit the `info.plist` you can just use a normal text editor like sublime text etc.):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domain.tld</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This will only allow requests to the domain you specified. The described way is the one which apple [introduced on the WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=711). As you can see on the screenshot, it's the way apple want the users to use it.

If you haven't specified anything, you'll get

> Failed to load webpage with error: The resource could not be loaded
>   because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.

So, change it like i said and the error is gone away.
[image]

Comment: I agree. Both will work, and you can get more specific if needed.

Comment: Not you **can**, you **should** be more specific! These are security topics which are not discussable in my opinion.

Comment: The second approach with whitelisting every single domain is definitely the way to go, the first one does not work in iOS prior to iOS9. (Tested on iOS 7)

Comment: I am facing almost same issue. I tried with above settings.

The same application is working fine in our QA server. But when I trying to connect to dev server, it is not working. It returns 

{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"}

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in an Xcode project you may have to edit the `info.plist` file. Security changed with iOS9. Apple is strongly recommending using https for web requests when possible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656803/angularjs-http-jsonp-ios9-404/32658386#32658386) is an answer related to this issue.

From that post:

Add this to your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> 
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

> App Transport Security (ATS) enforces best practices in the secure connections between an app and its back end. ATS prevents accidental disclosure, provides secure default behavior, and is easy to adopt; it is also on by default in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11. You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one.
>
> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: This worked for me. My app didn't load after updating device to iOS9, now it works like a charm. Life saver, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a combination of @area28's and @Sithys' answer. So I ended up adding this to my info.plist:

```
<dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.domain.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who may come across this in the future. I had the same issue and it turned out to be due to the SSL certificate being self-signed (development server). iOS 9 Cordova (UIWebView - not sure about WKWebView) would silently fail and return readyState:0, responseText:"", status:0

Android 7 did not have this issue.