# not allowed to load local resource ios9 cordova app

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

```html
<!--CSP Meta Tags in index.html -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src *;
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>

<!-- config.xml file with whitelist plugin -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.abc.testApp"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "2.0.0" >
  <name>TestApp</name>
  <description>
    Sample app to download and launch hybrid app
  </description>
  <author email="Test@gmail.com" href="http://1ct.es">
    Test
  </author>

  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="fullscreen"  value="true" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />

  <icon src="icon.png" />

  <content src="index.html" />
  
  <gap:platform name="ios" />
  
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.3" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.5.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.chromium.zip" version="2.1.0" />
  
  <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
      <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
      </dict>
  </gap:config-file>
 
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <allow-intent href="*" />
 <access origin="*" />
 
 
</widget>
```

This is the part of the code snippet to get the local path of the app and loading the path in an iframe:

```
var appLocalUrl = cordova.file.dataDirectory + AppId + "/index.html";
iframe[0].contentWindow.location.replace(appLocalUrl);
```

The app is downloaded to local path 
but when we try to launch this in iframe ended up with error message:

> not allowed to load local resource:{file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B8BF6DE2-228D-46B9-A84D-D2122D152385/Library/NoCloud/970/index.html}

Any help on this?

Comment: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) - Make sure you implement CSP.

Comment: Thanks but still I am facing the same issue.Please check the config.xml and meta tags added to the question.

Comment: You have NO tags that say you are using *Phonegap Build* and you have not mention in your post that your are using *Phonegap Build*. Are you using *Phonegap Build*, the cloud service from Adobe?

Answer (score 2):

So I have already struggled a lot related to this.
Latest iOS uses WKWebView. It appears to treat local files as if they came from a remote server, even though they're in the app itself, and such requests are blocked. Reference [Source](https://www.scirra.com/blog/ashley/25/hacking-something-useful-out-of-wkwebview)

The following solution worked for me:

1. Add the Corodova file plugin.

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`
2. Change the local file path to this:

   `cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/you_folder_name/file_name.mp3`