# react-native TypeError: network request failed

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

trying to authenticate application via #fetch() - throwing TypeError: ...

tried to add with my local ip add in appdelegate.m also,
 but didnt work

**please help - here is my code**

```
var test2 = React.createClass({
    _onPressButtonPOST: function() {
        fetch('https://test.xxx.com/authenticate/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username : 'uname',
           password : 'pw123',
           fingerprint : '12637pw',
          })
        })

            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseText) => {
              console.log(responseText);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.warn(error);
            });

    },  
    render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
      <Image source={require('./bg.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
              <ScrollView> 
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST} style={styles.button}>
                            <Text>POST</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
              </ScrollView> 

    </Image>
    </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: may be this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32710127/1206613

Comment: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

tried everything, getting this error.. try all the possible way to do this, any other solution for this

Comment: Should I need to add the domain and give the access to info.plist ? should that work ? or something went wrong from back-end (any additional ssl required for back-end) ?

Comment: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) 
getting this error.

Comment: @Mack That error sounds like the domain you're attempting to load doesn't have a valid SSL certificate associated with it. Can you verify that it does by visiting it in the browser and viewing cert details?

Comment: what I was accessing is https request to my localhost http, that was a problem. is there any way to convert localhost url to https:// localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true ?