# Cordova IOS 5.1.1 app running in IOS 14 causes CORS errors , same app. running in IOS 12.4 works

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

My app is issuing ajax requests to a remote server. The same app works ok in IOS 12.4 but in IOS 14 the ajax requests are failing for CORS related errors.

I see the origin sent as null

I see that IOS 14 forces an OPTIONS (http server log)request when we are only submitting a POST via ajax. This OPTIONS request is not sent by IOS on IOS version 12.4 (again same app). Also works fine in Android.

Is there a simple solution to this ?  I tried setting the CORS on server but I have not been successful.

I saw this post
[Cordova 10.0 Ajax not working in iOS 14 but working fine in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064651/cordova-10-0-ajax-not-working-in-ios-14-but-working-fine-in-android)

but did not offer a solution.

Error we see in javascript console

```
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://<server>:<port>/<subdirectory>/page.jsp?d=x due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (page.jsp, line 0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just spitballing... a couple of things that might be at play here:

1. You might need to upgrade to the latest cordova-ios (6.1.1), unless that's a typo in your description.
2. *Maybe* you're running into some of the tightened security enforced by the `WKWebView` in newer versions of cordova-ios. Try adding the following preferences to your `config.xml` file:

   ```
   <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
   <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
   ```

(Reference: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was not a typo. It is cordova-ios 5.1.1 . Same app works in IOS 12.4 . I am not sure why the request requires a preflight . Its a simple request based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests. To me it looks like a bug in IOS 14.